# Clojure jdbc - query single column flattened result

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I'm trying to read data (cca 760k rows) from a single column into one (flattened) vector. Result of `clojure.java.jdbc/query` is seq of maps, e.g. `({:key "a"} {:key "b"} ...)`. With option `:as-arrays? true` provided, `[[:key] ["a"] ["b"] ...]` is returned. To flatten the result, I've also used option `:row-fn first` and got `[:key "a" "b" ...]`. Finally, I've applied `rest` to get rid of the `:key`.

Wrapping and unwrapping of rows with vectors seems like a lot of unnecessary work. I'm also not happy with performance. Is there a faster / more idiomatic way? I've tried...

```
(jdbc/with-db-connection [con -db-spec-]
  (with-open [^Statement stmt (.createStatement (:connection con))
              ^ResultSet res  (.executeQuery stmt query)]
    (let [ret (ArrayList.)]
      (while (.next res)
        (.add ret (.getString res 1)))
      (into [] ret))))
```

... but it's not much faster, and it's ugly.

---

**EDIT**

Nicer way to do it is via transducers (see [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html#reading-and-processing-rows)):

```
(into []
      (map :key)
      (jdbc/reducible-query
       connection
       ["SELECT key FROM tbl"]
       {:raw? true}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `:row-fn :key`.  Not sure what performance you are expecting but on my i5 PC, retrieving 760K records took ~3 seconds (H2 file based database)

```clj
(time
 (count
  (jdbc/query db ["select top 760000 key from table1"] {:row-fn :key})))
;; => 760000

"Elapsed time: 3003.456295 msecs"
```